# Inconsistent overlay position because of different resolutions

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm using this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[1][0]scale2ref=w=iw/14:h=ow/mdar[logo][main];[main][logo]overlay=30:20" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

And the logo's position changes according to the video's size. I want the overlay to be in the same place.

left: 1152x480 and right: 1920x800

[image: Inconsistent overlay position because of different resolutions1]

Comment: Express overlay x and y in terms of video W and H, not absolute pixels.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan just saw your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this `overlay=W*.03:H*.03` which did the trick.